# Applying sort to DataFrameGroupBy groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
    brand         vehicleType
0   volkswagen      NaN
1   audi           coupe
2   jeep             suv
3   volkswagen     kleinwagen
4   skoda          kleinwagen
5   bmw             limousine
6   peugeot         cabrio
7   volkswagen      limousine
8   ford            bus
9   volkswagen     kleinwagen
10  mazda          limousine
11  volkswagen     kombi
12  volkswagen     kombi
13  volkswagen     kombi
14  nissan         suv
```

`d=df.groupby(['brand','vehicleType']).vehicleType.count()`

From the dataframe, I got the following table by performing the above operation

[image]

Now, how do I perform a descending sorting operation to the count column which is unnamed?

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns',  i think this error pops because d is not a dataframe??

Comment: Yeah. If you could post your original data (as text), that would be great.

Comment: nope it doesn't come ,i just wanted the counted values to be sorted in descending, other than that rest all should be the same

Comment: I assume by "rest all should be the same" you mean you want to preserve the brand order. If that's the case, use `d.sort_values(ascending=False).sort_index(level='brand', sort_remaining=False)`

Comment: I got it.Thank you so much:)

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Comment: Hmm, I think grouping and then sorting would be simpler @ayhan

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes, this has two different sorting operations (which might be unnecessary) but I thought it might be more efficient since sorting the index is generally fast. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Now from each group i have to pick just the top count, what should i do in this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to call `Series.groupby(level=0)`. To sort each group, you can use a lambda with `pd.Series.sort_values`:

```
d.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False))
```

---

To get the largest item from each group, sorting is no longer necessary. use `nlargest(1)`:

```
d.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(pd.Series.nlargest, n=1)
```

Comment: What is group_keys? what does it do?

Comment: 'group_keys=False' tell pandas that you don't want to add the group keys the the resulting dataframe (in this case it makes sense because your dataframe is already grouped with those keys)